# How to loop specific sections of code in Python?

Tags: python

I am an extreme novice and have only just started. I want to learn how to loop a specified section of my code.

```
#This program ask you to choose a number between 1 and 20, then tries to 
#guess it.

import random

print('Think of a number between 1 and 20, im going to try and guess it.')
print('If my guess is too high or low, please tell me and ill guess again.')
input()

guess=random.randint(1, 20)
print('Is this too high, too low, or correct?')
print(guess)
answer=input()

#Until the user answers 'correct' I would
#like all of the following to loop:
if answer == 'low':
    print('how about now?')
    guess=guess+1
    print(guess)
if answer == 'high':
    print('how about now?')
    guess=guess-1
    print(guess)
if answer == 'correct':
    print('nice!')
    print()
    print('Press CTRL+C to exit')
```

Comment: You're looking for a `while` loop. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Comment: Python loops are quite intuitive. From what you know so far what you you tried?

Comment: Side-note: Assuming this is for a class, they might be expecting you to perform binary search (possibly from a random starting point just to make it interesting). Adjusting your guess one at a time means `O(n)` guesses, while a binary search requires only `O(log n)` guesses. For a small range like this, the linear search isn't awful, but if the guessing game goes to larger ranges, incrementing or decrementing one at a time will take forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [while](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/whilestatements.html) loop.

First you need to decide on a condition that the loop will use to know when it's done.

```
while answer != 'correct':
```

Then the body of the loop comes after, so the whole thing would like this:

```
answer=input()

while answer != 'correct':
    if answer == 'low':
        ....
    if answer == 'high':
        ....
#code for correct comes after the while loop
```

Something to think about: what if the reply is neither 'correct', 'low' or 'high'?

Answer (score 0):

The while loop suggested by @munk ended up working. It looks like this.

```
#This program ask you to choose a number between 1 and 20, then tries to guess it.
import random
print('Think of a number between 1 and 20, im going to try and guess it.')
print('If my guess is too high or low, please tell me and ill guess again.')
input()

guess=random.randint(1, 20)
answer=input()
print('Is this too high, too low, or correct?')
print(guess)
answer=input()

#answer=input() at end of if statements is necessary to keep them from repeating
while answer != 'correct' :
    if answer == 'low':
        print('how about now?')
        guess=guess+1
        print(guess)
        answer=input()
    if answer == 'high':
        print('how about now?')
        guess=guess-1
        print(guess)
        answer=input()


 if answer == 'correct':
    print('nice!')
    print()
    print('Press CTRL+C to exit')
```

Answer (score -1):

You could have a function that could call itself again after every adjustment.

Let's call this function `adjust()`.

A basic function in Python looks like this:

```
def function( parameters, if any):
   #does something
   #does another thing
   return
```

So, let's put the adjustment 'if statements' you have inside the adjust() function. If the user answers 'low' or 'high', adjust will call itself again.

```
def adjust():

    print('Is this too high, too low, or correct?')

    print(guess)

    answer=input()

    #Until the user answers 'correct' I would
    #like all of the following to loop:

    if answer == 'low':
        print('how about now?')
        guess=guess+1
        print(guess)
        adjust()

    if answer == 'high':
        print('how about now?')
        guess=guess-1
        print(guess)
        adjust()

    if answer == 'correct':
        print('nice!')
        print()
        print('Press CTRL+C to exit')
```

And just call this after your initial guess, so that your code looks something like this:

```
#This program ask you to choose a number between 1 and 20, then tries to 
#guess it.
import sys
import random

print('Think of a number between 1 and 20, im going to try and guess it.')
print('If my guess is too high or low, please tell me and ill guess again.')
input()
guess=random.randint(1, 20)
adjust()

def adjust():

        print('Is this too high, too low, or correct?')

        print(guess)

        answer=input()

        #Until the user answers 'correct' I would
        #like all of the following to loop:

        if answer == 'low':
            print('how about now?')
            guess=guess+1
            print(guess)
            adjust()

        if answer == 'high':
            print('how about now?')
            guess=guess-1
            print(guess)
            adjust()

        if answer == 'correct':
            print('nice!')
            print()
            sys.exit(0) #quit the program
            #print('Press CTRL+C to exit')
```

You may also want to consider changing the if statement chain into a series of If-Else Ifs instead.

Comment: I'm not sure OP is quite ready for recursion. Further, because Python isn't tail call optimized, this will result in a stack overflow if the list is large enough.

Comment: I tried this, and I definitely see how this would solve my problem,but it keeps saying adjust is not defined?